# How can I create a discrete colorbar using a colormap from mpl_toolkits.basemap.cm?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, colormap

When I plot the pcolormesh plot use the colormap `from matplotlib.cm` (like `"jet"`, `"Set2"`, etc),   I can use:

```
 cMap = plt.cm.get_cmap("jet",lut=6)
```

The colorbar shows like this:

[image]

But if I want to call the colormap from the `Basemap` package (like `GMT_drywet`, `GMT_no_green`, etc). I can't use `plt.cm,get_cmap` to get these colormap and divide them.

Does `mpl_toolkits.basemap.cm` have a similiar function like `lut`?

Comment: What sort of plot are you trying to add a colorbar to? Could you show an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You can do this with the private method `_resample` on the color map objects.  Not strictly sure _why_ this method is private....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the plot you are making has discrete color values (e.g. `contour` or `contourf`), then `colorbar` should automatically generate a colorbar with discrete steps. Here's a plot based on [the first example from the `basemap` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html):

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.hold(True)

map = Basemap(projection='ortho',lat_0=45,lon_0=-100,resolution='l')
map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25)
map.drawcountries(linewidth=0.25)
map.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(0,360,30))
map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,30))

nlats = 73; nlons = 145; delta = 2.*np.pi/(nlons-1)
lats = (0.5*np.pi-delta*np.indices((nlats,nlons))[0,:,:])
lons = (delta*np.indices((nlats,nlons))[1,:,:])
wave = 0.75*(np.sin(2.*lats)**8*np.cos(4.*lons))
mean = 0.5*np.cos(2.*lats)*((np.sin(2.*lats))**2 + 2.)
x, y = map(lons*180./np.pi, lats*180./np.pi)

map.contourf(x,y,wave+mean,15, alpha=0.5, cmap=cm.GMT_drywet)
cb = map.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!   But when I use pcolor/pcolormesh type plot, it's not working.

Comment: That's because `pcolor` plots data using a continuously varying colormap rather than discrete levels. It would help if you edited your question to explain more clearly what result you are looking for, and show the code you are currently using to generate your plot.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on @tacaswell's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574934/how-can-i-create-a-discrete-colorbar-using-a-colormap-from-mpl-toolkits-basemap#comment56907682_34574934) above, you can achieve the same functionality using the `_resample` method. This will produce segmented colormaps for `pcolor`/`pcolormesh` plots which don't generate discrete-stepped colorbars like `contourf`. To achieve the same effect as you did with jet in your question:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import cm
plt.figure()
cmap = cm.GMT_drywet._resample(6)
pm = plt.pcolormesh(np.random.rand(10,8), cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar(pm, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

[image]