# Pleasant color maps that can be read to high accuracy

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, color-scheme

Does anyone know of color maps, arrays of say 50 colors, that

- can be read to high accuracy -- adjacant colors distinguishable by eye
- are visually pleasant ?

For example, the bottom color map under
[Matplotlib qualitative colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormaps.html#qualitative)

[image]

is pleasant, but has only 20 bands.
Can one get up to 50 bands, to read off height to within +- 2 % ?

("Visually pleasant" is somewhat, but not only, a matter of opinion;
there are objective criteria, from a tradition of map-making that goes back for centuries.
Here, the goals "50 bands" and "pleasant" conflict.)

---

Added: here are plots of some colormaps quantized to 20 bands,
4 "perceptually-uniform" from matplotlib
and 20-odd from [cmocean](https://matplotlib.org/cmocean),
"beautiful colormaps for oceanography".
It shows that even 20 bands are hard to distinguish where they're dark:

[image]
For real data, other factors will be more important than colormap alone:
interactive, e.g. zoom in with adaptive colormaps ?
[Histogram equalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) ?

Comment: I was actually trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44853305/4932316) answer which uses `resample`. It works for low number of bands but for 50 bands, it doesn't produce the required effect. For other continuous color maps, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54370143/4932316) answer by [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) works perfectly fine where you just replace `11` by `50`.

Comment: Possibly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47222585/matplotlib-generic-colormap-from-tab10/47232942#47232942) would help here. The idea would be to use `n` different hues and for each hue subdivide into `m` lightness grades to finally obtain `n*m` colors.